# Recursive wildcards to a specified directory

Tags: bash

Usually, I jump to a directory using a cumbersome way

```
 $ cd ~/*/*/*/2.Mathematics
```

the `*/*/*` is clumsy,

How could get it down with recursive globing

```
$ cd ~/**/2.Mathematics
-bash: cd: /home/me/**/2.Mathematics: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `shopt | grep glob`? You can check the affected array of dirs with `echo **`. Maybe what you need is [autojump](https://github.com/wting/autojump), also available [as a oh-my-zsh plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/autojump).

Comment: If `~/*/*/*/2.Mathematics` is `~/foo/bar/42/2.Mathematics` then set `CDPATH="~/foo/bar/42"` (in your `~/.bashrc`, e.g.) and use only `cd 2.Mathematics`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable globstar

```
shopt -s globstar
cd ~/**/2.Mathematics
```

Comment: Yes, tested with bash 4.3.48.